# Convert openpyxl to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After doing some research I understood that pandas can give us better performace comparing to openpyxl.
I'm trying to convert this code from openpyxl to pandas:

```py
    def get_restaurant_data(self, res: Restaurant, sf_id: int) -> RestaurantSchema:
        sheet = self.workbook["VendorInfo"]
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
            if row[0].value == sf_id:
                res.address = self.check_data(row[1].value, res.address)
                if self.check_data(row[2].value) and self.check_data(row[3].value):
                    res.loc = Point(row[3].value, row[2].value)
                res.phone = self.check_data(row[4].value, res.manager_phone)

                logo = self.download_file(row[5].value)
                cover = self.download_file(row[6].value)
                if logo:
                    res.logo.save(self.check_data(row[5].value), logo, save=False)
                if cover:
                    res.cover.save(self.check_data(row[6].value), cover, save=False)
                return RestaurantSchema(**res.__dict__)
```

Anyone can give me a suggestion about how to convert this code?

````
        df = pd.read_excel(self.path,index_col=None)
        print(f'>>>{df}')```
````

Comment: Pandas won't help you at all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_restaurant_data(self, res: Restaurant, sf_id: int) -> 
RestaurantSchema:
sheet = self.workbook["VendorInfo"]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
for i, row in df[1:].iterrows():
    if row[0] == sf_id:
        res.address = self.check_data(row[1], res.address)
        if self.check_data(row[2]) and self.check_data(row[3]):
            res.loc = Point(row[3], row[2])
        res.phone = self.check_data(row[4], res.manager_phone)

        logo = self.download_file(row[5])
        cover = self.download_file(row[6])
        if logo:
            res.logo.save(self.check_data(row[5]), logo, save=False)
        if cover:
            res.cover.save(self.check_data(row[6]), cover, save=False)
        return RestaurantSchema(**res.__dict__)
```

This code uses pandas to read the data from the "VendorInfo" sheet into a dataframe, and then uses the iterrows() method to iterate over the rows of the dataframe. The rest of the code is mostly the same as the original, with the exception of using the [] operator to access the values in each row instead of the value attribute.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, a lot! can I get higher performance here comparing to openpyxl?

Comment: @mehdiaria No, you can't. Pandas uses openpyxl under the hood anyway, and the bottleneck in your code 99% likely isn't parsing the XLS data.

Comment: And why are you using 'i' itrator on the loop while this is unused inside loop? is this ok?

Comment: In the for loop, i is an iterator that is used to iterate over the rows of the DataFrame. It is not used for anything else in the code.